# jQuery UI Slider - Min & Max values wrap in <span> tag

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to wrap the values of min & max variable of jQuery UI Slider into `<span>` tags which i want to be scroll beneath the slider handle.

The values of min and max should be wrapped into following tags:

`<span class="min-value></span>`

`<span class="max-value></span>`

**Here's the jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery('#slider-container').slider({
                range: true,
                min: 1200,
                max: 34000,
                values: [1200, 34000],
                create: function () {
                    jQuery("#amount").val("$1,200 - $34,000");
                },
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    jQuery("#amount").val("$" + ui.values[0] + "$" + ui.values[1]);
                    var mi = ui.values[0];
                    var mx = ui.values[1];
                    filterSystem(mi, mx);
                }
            })
        });

        function filterSystem(minPrice, maxPrice) {
            jQuery("li.column").hide().filter(function () {
                var price = parseInt(jQuery(this).data("price"), 10);
                return price >= minPrice && price <= maxPrice;
            }).show();
        }
```

The values should scroll along side the slider handle, how to do this?

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devyaqoob/n3L8gp1q/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read slider handle position in slide event:

HTML:

```
<div class="cs-widget">
<h3>Price Range</h3>

    <div class="cs-widget-content">
        <div id="slider-container"></div>
        <span class="min-value"></span>
        <span class="max-value"></span>
        <p class="clearfix">
        <input type="text" readonly id="amount" class="price-range" />
        </p>
        <div id="slider-range"></div>
      </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ui-slider {
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
}
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 1.1em;
    height: 1.1em;
    cursor: default;
    -ms-touch-action: none;
    touch-action: none;
    outline: none;
    background: #000;
    border-radius:50% 50%;
    border:1px solid #888;
    color:#fff;
}
.ui-slider .ui-slider-range {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: .7em;
    display: block;
    border: 0;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-color:#555;
}

/* support: IE8 - See #6727 */
.ui-slider.ui-state-disabled .ui-slider-handle,
.ui-slider.ui-state-disabled .ui-slider-range {
    filter: inherit;
}

.ui-slider-horizontal {
    height: .5em;
}
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-handle {
    top: -.5em;
    margin-left: -.6em;
}
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-range {
    top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-range-min {
    left: 0;
}
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-range-max {
    right: 0;
    content: "<";
}


/* Component containers
----------------------------------*/
.ui-widget {
    font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
.ui-widget .ui-widget {
    font-size: 1em;
}
.ui-widget input,
.ui-widget select,
.ui-widget textarea,
.ui-widget button {
    font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
}
.ui-widget-content {
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    background: #ccc;
    color: #222222;
}
.ui-widget-content a {
    color: #222222;
}
.ui-widget-header {
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    background: #000;
    color: #222222;
    font-weight: bold;

}
.ui-widget-header a {
    color: #222222;
}

.min-value, .max-value {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
}

.cs-widget-content {
    position: relative;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery('#slider-container').slider({
                range: true,
                min: 1200,
                max: 34000,
                values: [1200, 34000],
                create: function () {
                    jQuery("#amount").val("$1,200 - $34,000");
                },
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    jQuery("#amount").val("$" + ui.values[0] + "$" + ui.values[1]);
                    var mi = ui.values[0];
                    var mx = ui.values[1];
                    filterSystem(mi, mx);
                    $('.min-value').text(mi).css({left: $('#slider-container .ui-slider-handle:nth-child(2)').css('left')});
                    $('.max-value').text(mx).css({left: $('#slider-container .ui-slider-handle:last-child').css('left')});
                }
            })
        });

        function filterSystem(minPrice, maxPrice) {
            jQuery("li.column").hide().filter(function () {
                var price = parseInt(jQuery(this).data("price"), 10);
                return price >= minPrice && price <= maxPrice;
            }).show();
        }
```

Demo [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n3L8gp1q/1/)

Comment: Thanks. this is close to what i am after, please check this http://jsfiddle.net/devyaqoob/n3L8gp1q/2/ i made the `input` hidden because now i don't to show values twice only alongside the slider handle, which is now working only if we move the handle. Could it be visible on handle load as their initial min and  max values, and then if we want to slide so it slides as well?

Comment: You can add `create` event in initialization: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n3L8gp1q/3/)

Comment: Thank you very much :) one more thing, if i want to styled these values (for example adding a tooltip style background) where do i style it?

Comment: In CSS `.min-value` and `.max-value` these elements are normal HTML elements, there you can apply any CSS you need (only important thing is `position: absolute`)